# name 'snippets' is not defined [Django Rest]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am following the tutorial of Django REST Framework and when I try to curl `http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets`, I get that error. I am new to Python/the Framework and Django, so I don't have a clue where to look at.

The code seems to be pretty fine, since I have double checked on github. Where do you think the error should be?

Snippet/serializers.py

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from snippets.models import Snippet

    class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Snippet
            fields = ('id', 'title','code','linenos','language','style')
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.Field()  # Note: `Field` is an untyped read-only field.
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False,
                                  max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(widget=widgets.Textarea,
                                 max_length=100000)
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                       default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                                    default='friendly')
def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Create or update a new snippet instance, given a dictionary
        of deserialized field values.

        Note that if we don't define this method, then deserializing
        data will simply return a dictionary of items.
        """
        if instance:
            # Update existing instance
            instance.title = attrs.get('title', instance.title)
            instance.code = attrs.get('code', instance.code)
            instance.linenos = attrs.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
            instance.language = attrs.get('language', instance.language)
            instance.style = attrs.get('style', instance.style)
            return instance

        # Create new instance
        return Snippet(**attrs)
```

snippet/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('snippets.views',
    url(r'^snippets/$', 'snippet_list'),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 'snippet_detail'),
)
```

snippet/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)
@csrf_exempt
def snippet_list(request):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

@csrf_exempt
def snippet_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
    """
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        snippet.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Comment: Most wild guess is that you either do not have a name='snippets' assigned to a url or you haven't created a url for snippets. Is it demo that you're running? Could you show us some code?

Comment: What code do you want to look at? I know I have created a few files during the demo, so I wasn't sure what to post..

Comment: your `urls.py` and your `views.py`

Comment: Ok, I have edited the answer, what do you think?

Comment: You have defined a url pattern for `/snippets/` (note the trailing slash) but you are using curl to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets` (without the trailing slash).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem...

Comment: @Edoardo Moreni what is the line that crushes?

Comment: /private/var/root/tutorial/tutorial/urls.py in <module>, line 11

Comment: `from project.app.views import snippet_list` try this, but replace project and app with yours

Comment: try this one as well: `from django.conf.urls.defaults import *`

Comment: Do you mean in urls.py? It doesn't make much sense, since I am just following a tutorial that should be supposed to work. ?

Comment: yes, do this in `urls.py`. Maybe the tutorial didn't specify this because it was supposed to be obvious

Comment: @Edoardo Moreni your app is called `snippet` or `snippets` ? because you earlier said `snippet/urls.py`. Your app is supposed to be called `snippets`

Comment: @Edoardo Moreni are you sure your app is called `snippets`? plurla, not singular. show us your file tree structure please

Comment: manage.py snippets tmp.db  tutorial - yes, it's snippets.

Comment: ok, in this case, show us your both `urls.py` files. you have one at your project level, and one in your `snippets` app

Answer (score 2):

In your file `urls.py`, put quotes around `snippets.urls`.

Like this:

```
url(r'^',include('snippets.urls'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `serializers.ModelSerializer`:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title','code','linenos','language','style')
```

This lets DRF know to extract the fields and their types from the specified model class `Snippet`  as parameters for the serializer. Your current version is using only `serializers.Serializer`. With the base `Serializer` class you need to define field variables for it to work. like this example:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.Field()  # Note: `Field` is an untyped read-only field.
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False,
                                  max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(widget=widgets.Textarea,
                                 max_length=100000)
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                       default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                                    default='friendly')
```

Additionally, its probably a better practice for you to import your views from `views.py` like so:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.snippet_list, name='snippet-list'),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.snippet_detail, name='snippet-detail'),
)
```

Comment: I have updated the serializers.py, as I have posted above, but I am still getting the same error. Regarding the views, I am simply following the tutorial. : )

Comment: Can you please post the error you're getting? the tutorial works differently at different stages. I'm not sure that its supposed to work 100% of the time. Here's the completed version https://github.com/tomchristie/rest-framework-tutorial

Comment: I am on the last step here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization and trying to get "curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/".

Comment: Error: "NameError at /snippets/
name 'snippets' is not defined"

Comment: did you paste in the urls.py that I included in my answer?

Comment: also, in the tutorial it includes serializers.ModelSerializer as well

Comment: he doesn't need `as_view()`. He has functional views, not class based views.

Comment: Also did you create an app named `Snippets`?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my serializer above and in the file, I totally missed that but I think I am missing something else.

Comment: I have updated urls to your latest edit, but I still get the same thing. I might go back and rewrite every single file. :\

Comment: @EdoardoMoreni I would suggest that you continue with the tutorial until you get the last lesson. then you can compare you project with the official tutorial one I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

for me, what solved the problem is the file name.
make sure that the file `serializers` itself have no spelling issues and his name is the same as in the code.